# combining multiple json files into a single json file with jq filters

Tags: json, jq

I have multiple json files that I need to comnine into one giant json file.
I know I can use the basic -s and get a giant file
`jq -s . littlefiles*.json >> giantfile.json`

My issue is I cannot seem to figure out how to filter things out and still combine them into a valid json. All my efforts have yielded the right filtered output, but it's missing the "," between.  I've seen some answers on the webz on using "map" but I don't see its application on my filtering.  Maybe I'm using jq all wrong for what I need?

here's a cat of the jq

```
rfossi@xAMrfossi Responses % cat BBB.json | jq '.[] | { repo: .url[37:-1] | [rtrimstr("/branches/master/protectio")], PushUsers: [.restrictions.users[].login], PushTeams: [.restrictions.teams[].slug]}'
{
  "repo": [
    "homelaunch_basic"
  ],
  "PushUsers": [],
  "PushTeams": [
    "master-branch-mergers"
  ]
}
{
  "repo": [
    "homelaunch_base"
  ],
  "PushUsers": [],
  "PushTeams": []
}
```

As you can see, I get the info I need.  But it's missing the "," that makes it a valid json file.   When I attempt to combine the files with this same filtering, I get one of the dreaded **Cannot index array with string** messages (basic example below).  I've been looking at this too long I think, and I'm missing something obvious.

```
rfossi@xAMrfossi Responses % jq -r '.[] | { url: .url, users: [.restrictions.users[].login]}' B*.json > Bgiant.json
jq: error (at B1get-branch-prot-1641247960841.json:0): Cannot index string with string "url"
jq: error (at B2get-branch-prot-1641247961044.json:0): Cannot index string with string "url"
jq: error (at Bgiantfile.json:5): Cannot index array with string "url"
jq: error (at Bgiantfile.json:10): Cannot index array with string "url"
rfossi@xAMrfossi Responses %
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have received is two valid JSON documents (or a stream, as it is called in the jq manuals). If you put a comma in between, it wouldn't be valid JSON anymore because then it'd be neither a stream of two documents anymore (as of the superfluous comma) nor one array with two elements in it (as of no surrounding array brackets). You can, however, add those missing brackets, too, making it an array, if this is what you want.

To achieve this, surround your entire filter with brackets `jq '[.[] | {…}]'` and jq will take care of the commas. Also, as your filter's initial part `.[]` was already decomposing an array (or an object), you could simplify the array creation by exchanging it for a `map` with the same effect: `jq 'map({…})'`.

Comment: Thank you SO much for taking the time to break it down for me. It was the wrapper brackets!!  Also, thank you for including the info on map. I just want you to know that you have restored my faith on humanity and the internet (i'm only half kidding). Wishing you the best in '22 and beyond!  rmf ;)

Comment: Note: My final steps were:  
1. combined the files into one giant file without any filtering `jq -s . C*.json >> Ccombined.json`  
2. filtered the content of Ccombined.json file and saved it as json using `cat Ccombined.json| jq '[.[] | { repo: .url, PushUsers: [.restrictions.users[].login], PushTeams: [.restrictions.teams[].slug], ReviewCount: [.required_pull_request_reviews.required_approving_review_count], EnforceAdmins: [.enforce_admins.enabled], AllowForcePush: [.allow_force_pushes.enabled]}]' >> Cfiltered.json`