# Merging Instana EUM JSONs with JQ in CMD

Tags: json, batch-file, cmd, jq, instana

I'm using Instana to deliver view stats on my site, each daily file looks like this:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "page1.htm",
    "earliestTimestamp" : 1675222177839,
    "cursor" : {
      "@class" : ".IngestionOffsetCursor",
      "ingestionTime" : 1675292168217,
      "offset" : 1
    },
    "metrics" : {
      "uniqueSessions.distinct_count" : [ [ 1675292400000, 4.0 ] ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "page2.htm",
    "earliestTimestamp" : 1675260035165,
    "cursor" : {
      "@class" : ".IngestionOffsetCursor",
      "ingestionTime" : 1675292168217,
      "offset" : 2
    },
    "metrics" : {
      "uniqueSessions.distinct_count" : [ [ 1675292400000, 1.0 ] ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "page3.htm",
    "earliestTimestamp" : 1675228447118,
    "cursor" : {
      "@class" : ".IngestionOffsetCursor",
      "ingestionTime" : 1675292168217,
      "offset" : 3
    },
    "metrics" : {
      "uniqueSessions.distinct_count" : [ [ 1675292400000, 7.0 ] ]
    }
  } ],
  "canLoadMore" : false,
  "totalHits" : 12,
  "totalRepresentedItemCount" : 12,
  "totalRetainedItemCount" : 12,
  "adjustedTimeframe" : {
    "windowSize" : 86400000,
    "to" : 1675292400000
  }
}
```

These daily files should be merged into one json after filtering for the necessary info:

- url (from name)
- date (first value in "uniqueSessions.distinct_count")
- number of page visits: (second value in "uniqueSessions.distinct_count")
  It is important, that it has to be done in CMD, since I have to use a batch file as the target user is not allowed to run PowerShell scripts, nor have access to any other CL tool.

So far, I managed to boil down the files to the needed data elements as separate JSON objects using:  `type *.json | jq ".items[] | {url: .name, date: .metrics[][0][0], load: .metrics[][0][1]}"`

the result looks like:

```
{
  "url": "page1.htm",
  "date": 1675292400000,
  "load": 4
}
{
  "url": "page1.htm",
  "date": 1675292400000,
  "load": 1
}
{
  "url": "page1.htm",
  "date": 1675292400000,
  "load": 7
}
```

however, if I try to wrap it in square brackets (as tutorials suggest) to get a valid JSON,  I get one file with a bunch of arrays starting and ending where they did in the original files.
I did the homework, and  am aware of this: [combining multiple json files into a single json file with jq filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573060/combining-multiple-json-files-into-a-single-json-file-with-jq-filters) actually, I played around with this for a while now before asking. I was thinking if I could add again curly brackets and a root node, it would help, but I haven't found a way where JQ wouldn't fail to do noting, that most probably the error comes from windows cmd's quotation mark usage.

How can I make this into one JSON instead of as many arrays as many source files?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for using `map` instead of `.[]` to retain the array? [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rw4bTjvu5-k)

Comment: Thank you, my problem is, that I have several JSON files. In JQplay, I managed to get the filtering, like in your example, but for one file only. Once I read all jsons, the target file will have as many arrays as many original files I had. 
I saw your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302009/jq-map-objects-to-array-with-condition but it is also for filtering one input data (within 1 array) whereas I'll have one per day. 

Or maybe I still don't get what map does here?

Comment: With multiple inputs, you need some structure wrapping around all of them. Either use `--slurp` which wraps them into an array (which you can use `map` on), or call for each input in a superordinate loop like `reduce`. I have added an answer covering both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple input files, you can create another array around all of them using the `--slurp` (or `-s` option), then use `map` on that:

```bash
jq -s 'map(.items[] | {…})' *.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VBhllDZcLVt)

Or programmatically iterate (e.g.using `reduce`) over each input (using `inputs` in combination with the `--null-input` (or `-n`) flag):

```bash
jq -n 'reduce inputs as {$items} ([]; . + [$items[] | {…}])' *.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6TmFbubF6cI)

Comment: Thanks! Used the first one, works like a charm. 
(Sorry for replying late, was away for a while.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry. I'm afraid I don't know Instana nor JQ enough in order to exactly understand what you need... You have *not* show your desired final output file either... However, I *do* know Batch files enough!

The pure Batch file below process all `*.json` files and extract your "needed data elements" as you show above. This is a first step to get the right solution, because this Batch file could be modified in any way you need.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%f in (*.json) do (
   set "url="
   for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[:,] " %%a in ('findstr "name uniqueSessions" "%%f"') do (
      if not defined url (
         echo "url": %%a
         set "url=%%a"
      ) else (
         echo "date": %%a
         echo "load": %%~Nb
         set "url="
      )
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
"url": "page1.htm"
"date": 1675292400000
"load": 4
"url": "page2.htm"
"date": 1675292400000
"load": 1
"url": "page3.htm"
"date": 1675292400000
"load": 7
"url": "page4.htm"
"date": 1675292400000
"load": 3
"url": "page5.htm"
"date": 1675292400000
"load": 6
"url": "page6.htm"
"date": 1675292400000
"load": 2
```

Perhaps if you show us the desired output file, I could complete the solution

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late, I wasn't available for a while.
I have added this on a batch file, but it didn't deliver the results you show: 
both "url" and "date" contains URLs, leaving "load" blank

Comment: This is strange because I copied _the same data_ you posted above and use it as input data, so my program generate such results. Do you did _the same_? That is, use the data you posted above, not another, perhaps different data...

Answer (score 1):

Adding `|jq -s` to what you already have should work:

```bash
type *.json | 
jq ".items[] | {url: .name, date: .metrics[][0][0], load: .metrics[][0][1]}" |
jq -s
```

A trailing `jq -s` can do the array wrapping for you if you have a list of json objects like so:

```
§ cat input-malformed.json 
{ "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2 }
{ "a" : 11,
  "b" : 22 }

§ cat input-malformed.json | jq -s
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 11,
    "b": 22
  }
]
```

I don't have a Windows machine handy, but the bash equivalent on jq version 1.6 works (where a.json and b.json are copies of your input JSON documents):

```bash
cat a.json b.json | 
jq ".items[] | {url: .name, date: .metrics[][0][0], load: .metrics[][0][1]}" |
jq -s
```

Comment: Also tried this (after substituting the cat part with type *.json), and it gave the same result as @pmf's (who also included -s), so the answer is 100% CORECT, but since (s)he answered earlier I accepted that one. Thanks for looking into it!